# Website remember button press

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with to get my website remember a button press. Website automatically plays music and it has mute button, but it doesn't remember if you pushed the button when you go to next page or refresh the page. That local storage script doesn't seem to work.

```js
function mute(){
  var audio = document.getElementById("music")
  var toggle = document.getElementById("toggle")
  if (audio.muted == true) {
    audio.muted=false
    toggle.innerHTML ="MUTE"
  } else {
    audio.muted=true
    toggle.innerHTML ="UNMUTE"
  }
}
```

```html
 <audio id="music" autoplay loop>
        <source src="/files/music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        <source src="/files/music.ogg" type="audio/ogg"> Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
 <script>
  var audio = document.getElementById("music");
  audio.volume = 0.3;
</script>
<button id="toggle" class="toggle" onclick="mute()">MUTE</button>
<script>
localStorage.setItem('toggle', 'true');
localStorage.getItem('toggle'); // returns 'true'
</script>
```

Comment: even though local storage is more modern, you can set and get cookies in js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original script is setting `'toggle'` to `true` every time the page refreshes.

This should work as expected, see in JSFiddle (try press `Run` again after clicking the button to confirm it correctly stores the value): https://jsfiddle.net/kevinkassimo/m44vh2qy/
(the following code would not work due to snippet sandboxed environment)'

```html
<button id="toggle" class="toggle" onclick="toggle()">TOGGLE</button>
<h1 id="txt"></h1>
<script>
function toggle() {
  let isToggle = +localStorage.getItem('toggle');
  if (!isToggle) {
    localStorage.setItem('toggle', 1);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = 'Toggled';
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('toggle', 0);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = 'Not Toggled';
  }
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  if (+localStorage.getItem('toggle')) {
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = 'Toggled';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = 'Not Toggled';
  }
})
</script>
```

A working sample is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/kevinkassimo/a9o6mjnw/16/

Comment: I don't quite get this how should I implement this? When I press my 'mute' button it mutes the music and changes the button text to 'unmute' when I press that it plays music again. Trying to get website remember if you muted the music or not.

Comment: @trygaba use the same logic as my code: when user first visit site and when document is ready, you could check if localStorage has `mute` set to true. If not present, I assume it as false, save the default value, and render button text based on that (using normal DOM manipulation). Later when the user clicks the button, we update the localStorage `mute` value based on stored values and change the button text using DOM manipulation. When the user later revisit the page, we check the localStorage when document is loaded and set the button text based on that

Comment: @trygaba Check this out? https://jsfiddle.net/kevinkassimo/a9o6mjnw/16/

Comment: Got it finally working after I got it what I should do: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/0x8h1hyu/) Thanks for that also, figured it out by myself also but just took some time :) Your solution looks also good.

Comment: @trygaba Glad you figured it out. You can also compare to my version above in the previous comment

Answer (score 0):

Your IF statement checks for the Boolean of TRUE, but your local storage variable is set to the string “true”